# What's the differences between sticky-config MAC & sticky MAC on Huawei SW？

Tags: mac-address, port-security, huawei

In Port-security configuration，

```
port-security mac-address sticky-config xxxx-xxxx-xxx vlan x
port-security mac-address sticky xxxx-xxxx-xxx vlan x
```

1.All of them do not disappear after SW restarting. What's differences between the two commands？

2.Are sticky-config MAC & sticky MAC called security static MAC？

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the support articles I found

- [port-security mac-address sticky](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100214491?section=j0k7)
- [port-security mac-address sticky-config](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100214491?section=j0k6)

my understanding is that `sticky` is a basically dynamic mode where you can add MAC addresses manually as well. `sticky-config` is a static mode where there's no learning and all addresses need to be configured.

Both commands need to survive a reboot to make sense.

Comment: Your answer is not perfect. Sticky MAC can also be configure. Well, I notice your word "basically ".